# Error in Upgrading gwt 2.7 to 2.8 with java 1.8

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-material-design

**Currently project specification :-**

```
**

GWT version- 2.7
    Java - 1.8
    Eclipse - Luna
    GWT material- 2.0 rc3
    Tomcat version - Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
    Couchdb- 1.6.1
    neo4j- 2.3.2
```

**

**REQUIREMENT:-**

*We want to upgrade GWT from 2.7 to 2.8 according to our requirement to use GWT material 2.0 rc3 version.*

Now,The problem is for hosting the project on tomcat we have to put the jar files in project WEBINF lib folder. Our project works fine till we don't add any jar in lib except the servlet.jar as soon we add the jars in the lib folder and compile the project and run it following error comes.

**ERROR:-**

```
The code server is ready at http://127.0.0.1:9876/
Code server started in 2.803 s ms
2017-01-26 11:57:47.630:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.z-SNAPSHOT
2017-01-26 11:57:53.544:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED c.g.g.d.s.j.WebAppContextWithReload@632a82{/,file:/E:/ServerWorkSpace/enggheads/war/,STARTING}{E:\ServerWorkSpace\enggheads\war}: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.juli.logging.Log: Provider org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JuliLog not a subtype
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.juli.logging.Log: Provider org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JuliLog not a subtype
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.<init>(LogFactory.java:78)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.<clinit>(LogFactory.java:66)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.<init>(JspServlet.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet.<init>(JettyJspServlet.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$Context.createInstance(ContextHandler.java:2372)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$Context.createServlet(ServletContextHandler.java:1166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.newInstance(ServletHolder.java:1207)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:871)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:759)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:634)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:923)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:706)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:430)
2017-01-26 11:57:53.544:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler@4cb6a9: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.juli.logging.Log: Provider org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JuliLog not a subtype
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.juli.logging.Log: Provider org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JuliLog not a subtype
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.<init>(LogFactory.java:78)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.<clinit>(LogFactory.java:66)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.<init>(JspServlet.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet.<init>(JettyJspServlet.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$Context.createInstance(ContextHandler.java:2372)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$Context.createServlet(ServletContextHandler.java:1166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.newInstance(ServletHolder.java:1207)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:871)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:759)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:634)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:923)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:706)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:430)
2017-01-26 11:57:53.544:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@1adf81d{HTTP/1.1}{127.0.0.1:8888}
2017-01-26 11:57:53.544:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@18a53a2: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.juli.logging.Log: Provider org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JuliLog not a subtype
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.juli.logging.Log: Provider org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JuliLog not a subtype
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.<init>(LogFactory.java:78)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.<clinit>(LogFactory.java:66)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.<init>(JspServlet.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet.<init>(JettyJspServlet.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$Context.createInstance(ContextHandler.java:2372)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$Context.createServlet(ServletContextHandler.java:1166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.newInstance(ServletHolder.java:1207)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:871)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:759)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:634)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:923)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:706)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:430)
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.juli.logging.Log: Provider org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JuliLog not a subtype
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.<init>(LogFactory.java:78)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.<clinit>(LogFactory.java:66)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.<init>(JspServlet.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet.<init>(JettyJspServlet.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$Context.createInstance(ContextHandler.java:2372)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$Context.createServlet(ServletContextHandler.java:1166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.newInstance(ServletHolder.java:1207)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:871)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:759)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:634)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:923)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:706)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:430)
```

I tried to study about it , in some places it asked to delete the cache files from the project I did the same. Deleted the cache files except no-cache. deleted the classes created in project on complie.

On Compiling the project its taking only 1 permutation.

Totally, unaware of the problem that whats the problem in adding the jar files in lib folder.
As, its clear we cant host the project without adding the jars in lib. So what is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**REMOVED THE gwt-dev.jar from the lib and it worked totally fine. Something i was totally unaware of it could also create problem.**